# understanding spyder's profiler results python

Tags: python, spyder

I'm using python 2.7.11 and spyder's (v2.3.8) profiler, but I have trouble understanding the results. 
This is an image of the results ordered by "Total Time"

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1) `mainloop` uses 216.012 Total Time. How can I know what part/line of my code is calling those functions?

2) In the function `noise_kauff` (wich I defined) Total Time is 20.51 but the first line inside `noise_kauff` uses 51.629?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that the time and call values shown by [spyder-profiler] are global to the execution of the program and not specific to a particular call. Because of this, some functions/methods may show longer times than their callers.

http://sjara.github.io/spyder-profiler/

In your example, presumably `__getitem__` ran for about ten seconds from within `noise_kauff` plus for about half a minute from elsewhere. Unfortunately spyder just adds those together - it's a known issue/bug.